# Converting array of options to hash

Tags: ruby

What is the most elegant way to break the following array

```
["name:alex", "age:14"]
```

into the following hash:

```
{:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}
```

Comment: The most elegant way would be not having such an array. How did you end up with it?

Comment: Business requirements are not always ideal, are they?

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby 2.1 arrays ship with the [to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method

```
p ["name:alex", "age:14"].map{|el| el.split(":")}.to_h #=>{"name"=>"alex", "age"=>"14"}
```

With symbols as keys:

```
["name:alex", "age:14"].map{|el| k,v = el.split(":"); [k.to_sym, v]}.to_h
```

Comment: output is `{:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}` , so a bit extra work you need to do. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You need to split each pair, and convert the results to a hash with `Hash[]`:

```
array = ["name:alex", "age:14"]

Hash[array.map { |s| s.split(':') }]

# => {"name"=>"alex", "age"=>"14"}
```

This takes advantage of Ruby's convention for freely converting between arrays and hashes. Given an array `[[a, b], [c, d]]`, each element is considered to be a `[key, value]` pair. You only need to turn your array from `["name:alex", "age:14"]` into `[['name', 'alex'], ['age', '14']]` and `Hash[]` will do the rest. Conversly, you can call `.to_a` on a Hash and produce the an array containing `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...]`.

If you want the keys to be symbols, you can add that to the `map`:

```
Hash[array.map { |s| pair = s.split(':'); [pair.first.to_sym, pair.last] }]
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to go :

```
a = ["name:alex", "age:14"]
hsh =  a.each_with_object({}) do |s,h| 
  k,v = s.split(":")
  h[k.to_sym] = v
end
hsh # => {:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}
```

Comment: This works, but `Hash[]` and `to_h` are a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way using [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
array = ["name:alex", "age:14"]

array.reduce({}) { |a, e| k, v = e.split(':'); a.merge({k.to_sym => v}) }
# => {:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}
```

Comment: In terms of performance this is brutal, it creates a whole bunch of garbage objects in the process of doing its thing, two new hashes per key. `Hash[]` and `to_h` are way better.

Comment: I know, also its better to use the bang .merge! instead but I tend to avoid mutable variables when performance is not big deal. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Merging in one key is with `merge!` is pretty heavy-handed, especially when `a[k.to_sym] = v; a` would do the job. Also consider `each_with_object` which is handy for situations like this and simplifies chaining.

Answer (score 0):

I would use tap and scan, and no semicolon.

```
a = ["name:alex", "age:14"]
{}.tap { |h| a.each{ |e| e.scan(/(\w+):(\w+)/) { |k, v| h[k.to_sym] = v } } }

# => {:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr = ["name:alex", "age:14"]

arr.group_by{|str| str.split(":")}.keys.each_with_object({}){|ele, h|
  h[ele.first.to_sym] = ele.last}

# => {:name=>"alex", :age=>"14"}
```